# Running and debugging Node / Express applications with cloud 9

Tags: node.js, debugging, express, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud 9 to develop a Node.js application with the Express framework. Currently, I can run my application by opening a new run configuration terminal, providing the absolute path to the www file of my Express app and pressing the run button in the terminal. I can go to a browser and open my application. If I open my www file and press the run button at the top of the screen, I get the error "bash: myApp/bin/www: No such file of directory. process exited with code: 127" If I open my app.js file and press the run button up top, the app appears to start, I get the log messages that would indicate things are all set, the debugger connects on port 15454 but I can't access my app from a browser with my usual c9 url. How can I run my Node app with the run button at the top of the page? What is the difference between that one and run terminal? Why is there no debug option when running with the run terminal? I can open the debugging panel from the tab on the right when I run the app from the run terminal, but the code doesn't stop at my breakpoints. I watched the tutorial on debugging in cloud 9. My breakpoints are inside a route if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You asked multiple questions, so I'll try to address each, do let me know if I missed something:

> Currently, I can run my application by opening a new run configuration terminal, providing the absolute path to the www file of my Express app and pressing the run button in the terminal.

Which runner are you using? For Node apps, use the `Node.js (default)` runner. I'm attaching a screenshot showing the various parts of the run panel and how you should configure it for your app:

[image: run panel]

1. Name your run configuration. This saves it and lets you access it from the run button in the menu. You can switch between different run configurations by right-clicking on the run button as shown in the image below:

[image: run button]

2. The path of the node script you want to run.
3. Enable Debugger. In the screenshot, the debugger is disabled, you can enable it by clicking the bug button
4. This shows the current runner. You can change it by clicking on it. You can also edit a default runner to suit your needs. To edit a runner, select it first, then re-open the dropdown and click on 'Edit Runner' near the bottom of the dropdown
5. Select the Node.js (default) runner.

> If I open my www file and press the run button at the top of the screen, I get the error "bash: myApp/bin/www: No such file of directory. process exited with code: 127"

Is www a Node script? Since the runners are detected using the file extension, if a file doesn't have one, the default 'shell command' is used. When bash tries to run your file, it doesn't know how to run it. If it's a directory, you cannot execute a directory anyway, so that won't work.

> If I open my app.js file and press the run button up top, the app appears to start, I get the log messages that would indicate things are all set, the debugger connects on port 15454 but I can't access my app from a browser with my usual c9 url.

Does app.js have the server listening code? Is it the main point of entry for your app? If not, run that file instead. You can only access your app if it's running and listening on 0.0.0.0 using one of ports 8080, 8081, or 8082.

Hope this helps. If not, please write to support@c9.io with details and we'll take a look.